# How to delete data in oracle 11g permanently so it can't be restored even under admin?

Tags: oracle11g

I need to give administrative access to the copy of database to third parties, but before that I need to delete some of the data. How do I do it so that even the administrator could not restore deleted data?

I delete the values using the command:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET my_column_name = NULL;
```

Then I drop AWR snapshots:

```
EXECUTE dbms_workload_repository.drop_snapshot_range(low_snap_id => ... , high_snap_id => ...);
```

what else should I do to completely and permanently delete data in oracle 11g?

Answer (score 1):

One option is:

1. `UPDATE` the values to remove the data.
2. Export the relevant tables using the `EXPDP` (or `EXP`) utility.

   - The export should consist of plain-text SQL statements and, if you want, you can review the statements to ensure the data is redacted at this point.
3. Create a new database instance.
4. Import the exported data into the new instance using the `IMPDP` (or `IMP`) utility.

Then the previous values will never have existed in that database instance.